# Assume that n is odd. Consider the following sum: $\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \cdots + \binom{n}{\frac{n-1}{2}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Help i don't understand this question
Assume that n is odd. Consider the following sum:

$$
{n \choose 0} + {n \choose 1} + \cdots + {n \choose (n-1)/2}
$$

(a) Write this sum using Riemann sum notation.
(b) How many terms does this sum have?
(c) Show that the sum has an even number of terms that are odd.

Answer (score 2):

The Riemann sum notation is: $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{(n-1)/2}\binom{n}{i}$$

---

It has $(n-1)/2+1$ terms.

---

$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\dots \binom{n}{(n-1)/2}=2^{n-1}$. Since the sum is even it has an even number of odd terms.